# How to render a Component hosted in S3 inside of a React / Next Application?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, next.js, dynamic

We are trying to implement a feature allowing users to add components hosted in an S3 file inside a Next / React application.

The application allows users to create small websites and apps (Projects) using a "Block style" architecture. Users can edit content in real-time using a drag-and-drop approach.

We want to enable users to create their own components and add them to their projects. Examples of components include a data table, an image and text section, a chatbox, etc.

[Example of component in a project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybNPl.jpg)

Our first approach consists of storing the JSX markup code (Compiled) for the component inside of an S3 file; and dynamically fetch the file in the client when requested.

It doesn't seem to work, though. When logged, the code content of the file is correct, but it doesn't render.

[The component doesn't render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGCI4.png)

We're trying different solutions, but I wonder if we shouldn't take an entirely different approach.

- Should we host component files as entire react projects in S3 rather than just the "markup" code?
- Or maybe not use S3?

Here is a working [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/quirky-hermann-crpn6x?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu0njfw700063b6kneo5gel8%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%252C0%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu0njfw700023b6k49f5pcuv%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu0njfw700033b6k8yygsa2i%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu0njfw700053b6kunfgkdsj%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clu0njfw700023b6k49f5pcuv%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu0njfw700013b6kown56vf9%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Findex.tsx%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu0njfw700023b6k49f5pcuv%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clu0njfw700013b6kown56vf9%2522%257D%252C%2522clu0njfw700053b6kunfgkdsj%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu0njfw700043b6kjlsbyroe%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu0njfw700053b6kunfgkdsj%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clu0njfw700043b6kjlsbyroe%2522%257D%252C%2522clu0njfw700033b6k8yygsa2i%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu0njfw700033b6k8yygsa2i%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Afalse%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

Below is the code we currently use to fetch content from the S3 file and render it:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, ComponentType } from "react";
// import { _jsx as _jsx, _jsxs as _jsxs } from "react/jsx-runtime";
// import * as JSXRuntime from "react/jsx-runtime";


const RenderRemoteComponent = ({}) => {
  const [Component, setComponent] = useState<ComponentType<any> | null>(null);

  const MyComponent =
    "https://boltcomponents.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/compiled-test.js?response-content-disposition=inline&X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEAgaCXVzLXdlc3QtMSJHMEUCIC0647aBXXIIKGkE7XemO3V1MFb7bILQS0fhrbmS85T3AiEA5lccIZqFzQFA9irKSov5uIN%2FWKmbTFarUik3OQnLKBgq6AIIIRAAGgwyMTk0Mzk3MjcwMTQiDE5LosSgzmIlR6EkRyrFAsvHEGDpoEAECnymKc8ck2EX8FA6qibAK54DvqkI%2FT2E6UnxB01bfs%2Fm2h9pUHsGZbPDRFkABwnPE0O32Twt%2Bq4zNHAYbQJCGU53ReJBfmT%2B1%2B3C4umykFl9Li1DmR6Bi4KJUZdD4ZeKxu3FIW%2FGzOZviZCpLw%2FGDnJ3%2BPDpH4OHdJvDijbB%2FY1oS1SUZEzOfPguMLSbjKvaQfnqocYjbHwDiBIAJNiBcZm7plfgCTT1fFC5BBBTAdYWvBLbtVV5OIuBcJ1Zjr4soTJpLu4%2Fxl1H7LpxSbgidFK6BRFyNF0L%2FScIjeaOqgH%2BMy9a6Ync9GyozW2bspZvuahkSvMix%2FZzjP2DxD8OPwP6fhPUxyZsyXKSl06kDybDnWlpmBZxX7btHQMa0rmrSaSkKrME2tKOj%2FMftSXJSuosF3OeZab5CGUUbBMwi%2FLtrwY6swJfOvblt7hBtemPejsolXmvbvPJ2297DnOLsGyfYepS90PoVobw%2BIRG3qjyee3B2AZGtJuGS2DTbW0hmfiS4eGabnCKjwsr1C%2BxLycQvcsf1sIaLp8q2zzrmjVwOV2m%2FfzfMONmFK0%2B4N6HpMYg5QT4T9bYMnSu%2FN%2FBlSbK78pzDwNmeSfaBSBG5AfTrusWptr681xKvIyT8%2BjZnRE8CzPiburq7GKJpFtiCQqK1onOTz%2BaxtrHM4pzpafPcX3Xs%2BZJU8d4T%2BBXQ%2BQuQ%2Fs82q%2FymfsdAppZvyTI5kd7ATqJBVfneKYCARWinBnitxJWJL9QcefsYqh4TRcSDjU0n5cpHqUtm0RCTWuw7CccR5%2FuezNt1rp%2FD965LPYgbD%2FmKttj4ytylf1rx8g1V25eYCY7h1ur&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20240321T011938Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=43199&X-Amz-Credential=ASIATGF5AQGTOFLFGNFD%2F20240321%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=155c73bedbe27d1503bd4264a2ffb7e2d80bfe7827701e5b797d7fe2a218a1c4";

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(MyComponent)
      .then((res) => res.text())
      .then((jsCode) => {
        console.log("Fetched JS Code:", jsCode);
        // Provide React and JSX runtime methods in the scope of the evaluated code
        const Module = new Function("React", "JSXRuntime", "return " + jsCode);
        // Assuming the module's default export is the component
        const ComponentModule: { default: ComponentType<any> } = Module(React, JSXRuntime);
        setComponent(() => ComponentModule.default);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Failed to load and compile the component:", error);
      });
  }, [MyComponent]);

  if (!Component) {
    return <div>Loading component...</div>;
  }

  // Using 'as' to assert the component type
  return <Component />;
};

export default RenderRemoteComponent;
```

Below is the code stored in the S3 file:

```
import { jsx as _jsx, jsxs as _jsxs } from "react/jsx-runtime";

// Define the component
const MyComponent = () => {
  return /*#__PURE__*/ _jsxs("div", {
    className: "block relative border rounded-lg overflow-hidden",
    children: [
      /*#__PURE__*/ _jsx("div", {
        className: "w-full bg-overlay z-0",
        children: /*#__PURE__*/ _jsx("img", {
          src: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1708257106465-7e2b14997ab9?q=80&w=2244&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D",
        }),
      }),
      /*#__PURE__*/ _jsxs("div", {
        className: "p-5 z-50 w-full h-full ",
        children: [
          /*#__PURE__*/ _jsx("h5", {
            className: "mb-2 text-xl font-medium leading-tight ",
            children: "Example Title",
          }),
          /*#__PURE__*/ _jsx("p", {
            className: "mb-4 text-base",
            children: "This is example text for the content area.",
          }),
          /*#__PURE__*/ _jsx("button", {
            type: "button",
            className:
              "bg-blue-500 inline-flex items-center justify-center text-white whitespace-nowrap rounded-md text-sm font-medium h-10 px-4 py-2",
            children: "Click Here",
          }),
        ],
      }),
    ],
  });
};

// Export the component
export default MyComponent;
```

Comment: code doesn't seem to get fetched. Have you tried removing `MyComponent` from the useEffect arry?